# Graph API for iOS Push Notifications - Confused AAD customer on Partner Portal

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-notifications

I want to use Microsoft Graph to send our company mobile app push notifications as discussed at Microsoft Build 2019.

I am following [Integrate with Microsoft Graph notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-e2e-overview). It directs me to create a "Developer Account" to use the Partner Portal but my company already has an Enterprise Azure account with Microsoft and we leverage Azure AD.

I've tried the "Onboard" step but then I read "To get started, sign in to the Partner Center dashboard using your Windows developer account (you cannot use an Azure AD account)". I'm very confused.

Also, the Partner Portal shows no items under the menu no matter how I signed in. I tried using a personal account and my AAD account and I get the same result. No menu items at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting a "Developer Account" from but the first step is [registering your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration). This gives you an Application Id and Secret which is required to authenticate against Graph:

> In order for your application service to integrate with Microsoft Graph notifications, you need to register your app with the Microsoft identity platform to support Microsoft accounts or work or school accounts, and declare the API permissions that are required.

With regards to the [windows developer account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-cross-device-experiences-onboarding), this is explained in the documentation:

> If you don’t already have a Windows developer account, you’ll need to create one. For details, see [Opening a developer account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account). You need to do this even if you don’t plan to build a Windows UWP application. If you’re building a school or work application as part of an enterprise, you can associate your developer account with the appropriate Azure AD account that is used for managing your enterprise submissions. For details, see [Associate Azure Active Directory with your Partner Center account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/associate-azure-ad-with-partner-center).